# File with domain list and count domain tld with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `test.txt` with this data

```
a.com
b.com
c.net
c.online
c.unknowntld
ccc.unknown
```

How i can count all `.com .net .online .unknowntld .unknown` in `test.txt`

So i want get like this :

```
.com : 2
.net : 1
.online : 1
.unknowntld : 1
.unknown : 1
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and str splitting to count.

```py
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()

with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        tld = line.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)[-1]
        cnt[tld] += 1

cnt  # Counter({'com': 2, 'net': 1, 'online': 1, 'unknowntld': 1, 'unknown': 1})
```

If you need the leading period, you can just prepend it in the counter key `cnt[f".{tld}"]`.